# How to increase values with sails-mysql?

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I want

```
UPDATE `some_table` SET `count` = `count` + 1 WHERE `id` = 1
```

I find a way like this

```
SomeModel.find(1).done(function (model){
    model.count += 1;
    model.save()
})
```

How to do this with `Model.update()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not do this with `Model.update()`. You can do it with `Model.query()`

You can also create your own model method to make it more DRY.

```
// Model.js  

module.exports = {
    attributes : {/*...*/},
    addToCount : function(id, cb) {
       Model.query('Update "some_table" SET "count" = "count" + 1 where "id" = ' + id).exec(function(err) {
        if(cb) {
            if(err) return cb(err);
            return cb();
         } else {
            return;
         } 
      }
    })
}
```

In your controller.js

```
Model.addToCount(id, function(err){
    /* optional call back  */
});
```